# To initiate a phone call from iphone websites

Tags: javascript, iphone, html

To make a phone call via HTML on an iPhone I have create an a tag with an href formatted as:
`<a href='tel:555-555-5555'>555-555-5555</a`>.

But My problem is, Its not working its opening in new tab just showing like its stuck.Even i tried `<a href="tel://555-555-5555">555-555-5555</a>` but non of them is working for me. Is anyone face these type of problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you first attempt seem to be the correct one, as you can see in de [Apple URL scheme documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/PhoneLinks.html).

There example:

> ```
> <a href="tel:1-408-555-5555">1-408-555-5555</a>
> ```

It might be the quotes, you use `'` while normally you would use `"`.

Comment: Just gave it a try on my iPhone and it works with the example given by apple. Are you testing it on a iPhone? The `tel:` scheme is not supported by iPad or iPod Touch, since they do not have a phone.

Comment: <a href="tel:1-408-555-5555">1-408-555-5555</a> or <a href='tel:1-408-555-5555'>1-408-555-5555</a> both work fine, in my case there is some problem with my nativ application. Thanks @rckoenes for your response.